# Widen a landscape table

Tags: tables, landscape

Any idea on how to make this landscape table wider (i.e. more extended across the width of the page)

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Value of the force local maximums (F\textsubscript{i} and F\textsubscript{Q}) and magnitude of the associated load drops observed in the load-displacement curves of impacted and indented LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI}, LV1\textsubscript{LVI} and LV2\textsubscript{LVI} specimens, $\pm$ refers to the standard deviation between experiments.}
    \label{Table3pD}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
        \hline
        Material & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Test}                                                                          \\ \cline{2-7} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at 10 J} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at 14 J} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{QSI} \\ \cline{2-7} 
        & F\textsubscript{i} (kN)              & Load drop (\%)       & F\textsubscript{i} (kN)              & Load drop (\%)         & F\textsubscript{Q} (kN)      & Load drop (\%)   \\ \hline
        LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI}    & 3.24 $\pm$ 0.02       & 19.75 $\pm$ 0.55       & 3.41 $\pm$ 0.25       & 22.80 $\pm$ 1.40       & 3.32     & Multiple     \\
        LV1\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.19 $\pm$ 0.04       & 14.64 $\pm$ 2.55       & 3.24 $\pm$ 0.22       & 11.34 $\pm$ 4.46       & 3.10     & Multiple     \\
        LV2\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.51 $\pm$ 0.15       & 8.17 $\pm$ 2.36        & 3.95 $\pm$ 0.51       & 10.80 $\pm$ 1.28       & None     & None         \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: You may want to use `tabularx` or similar environments

Comment: If you use tabularx, use \linewidth instead of \textwidth in the landscape environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can always (landscape or not) replace

```
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
```

by

```
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccccc@{}}
```

to spread the table to the current line width, although separating columns just makes the table harder to read.